# Spring Security Login form

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I need your help. I need to use default login form of Spring Security. When I start the webapp, it should open login page and after successful login redirect user to my jsp page without looking role (admin or just user). I tried this:

```
<http auto-config="true" create-session="stateless"
    use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/_ah*" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="working_sql_script"
            authorities-by-username-query="other_working_sql_script" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

But it opens blank page on start and I need to go to login page typing in browser: `http://webapp/spring_security_login` . How I can configure this to open login page on start and redirect to my JSP after login? Also, I wrote in web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

but it still open blank page on start.

Comment: where is the authentication provider specified here?

Comment: here's a nice example, http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/ hope it helps.

Comment: I updated my question. This example in link did not help me. I can't run this application. It says java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener . Bu I'm sure that this class in classpath and I created WEB-INF/lib folder and copy to this folder all required jars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to define one page in application with no restriction of role. and set that page as default form-login. On authentication success redirect to other page.

My spring-security.xml portion of code is as below

```
 <http pattern="/login" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/accessDenied" security="none"/>
<http auto-config="true">
    <remember-me/>
    <!-- Don't set any role restrictions on login.jsf -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/admin/*" access="ROLE_SADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/applicants/*" access="ROLE_SADMIN,ROLE_APPLICANT" />

    <!-- Set the login page and what to do if login fails -->
    <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login"
                default-target-url="/manageHome" authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>

    <logout success-handler-ref="customLogoutSuccessHandler" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="customAccessDeniedHandler"/>

</http>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have task: do not use custom login form. Only default

Comment: for that you can restrict all pages and in web.xml specify one page as welcome page, before redirecting to it, spring security will prompt to login.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all, who tried to help me. I solve this problem. And write this post for other developers who will face such problem. I created welcome page with access for all users and anonymous. Code of page:

```
<a href="index">Catalog</a>
<br>
<a href="registration">Registration</a>
```

my spring-security file contains this:

```
<http auto-config="true" create-session="stateless"
    use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome" access="isAnonymous()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/registration" access="isAnonymous()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/index" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <form-login default-target-url="/main"/>
</http>
```

and main page that is secured:

```
<h2>Catalog</h2>
<a href="logout">Logout</a>
<a href="goods">Goods</a>
<a href="vendors">Vendors</a>
```

Spring Security allows access to this page only after login. Login page generated by Spring Security. Hope, this will help to someone.